# How to move cursor to end of each line when editing multiple lines in Visual Studio Code with different line length?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can select all lines without any problem but don't know to go end of each line when they are different in length (short or long)!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and click at the end of each line individually
- Click at the end of the **longest line** of the text you are trying to select and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and use your up or down arrow key to add a cursor to the rest of the lines you wish
- Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and use your up or down arrow key to add a cursor to all the lines you wish, and then press the <kbd>End</kbd> key as this .gif illustrates:

[image: animated .gif showing how to select multiple lines and go to the end of them]